# Reemplazar caracteres especiales en observaciones en varias columnas en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un dataset importado de Google Sheets que cuando lo importo usando el paquete "googlesheets4" me trae varias columnas como en este ejemplo:

```
Provincia                        `Home Office` `¿Tenés hijos?`
   <fct>                            <fct>         <fct>          
 1 Corrientes                       No            NA             
 2 CÃ³rdoba                         SÃ­            SÃ­             
 3 Ciudad AutÃ³noma de Buenos Aires SÃ­            SÃ­             
 4 Buenos Aires                     SÃ­            SÃ­             
 5 Buenos Aires                     SÃ­            No             
 6 Ciudad AutÃ³noma de Buenos Aires SÃ­            No             
 7 Ciudad AutÃ³noma de Buenos Aires SÃ­            No             
 8 Ciudad AutÃ³noma de Buenos Aires SÃ­            No             
 9 Ciudad AutÃ³noma de Buenos Aires SÃ­            SÃ­             
10 Ciudad AutÃ³noma de Buenos Aires SÃ­            No
```

Una forma de reemplazarlo sería por ejemplo:

```
data %>%
mutate(Provincia = str_replace_all("Ã³", "ó"))
```

Y así sucesivamente con cada columna (en total son 40, esto es sólo una muestra). ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo eficientemente? ¿Con un loop o hay algún paquete que pueda resolverme este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Primero tu pregunta. Tienes un error en el uso de `str_replace()` debiera ser en todo caso algo así: `mutate(Provincia = str_replace_all(Provincia, "Ã³", "ó"))`, ahora si quieres aplicar esto a múltiples columnas al mismo tiempo podrías hacer algo así:

```
data %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, str_replace_all, "Ã³", "ó")
```

Usamos `mutate_if` para aplicar el cambio solo en las columnas que cumplan  cierta condición, en tu ejemplo, pareciera que las cadenas las tratas como factores por lo que chequeamos mediante `is.factor`, luego en los siguientes parámetros pasamos la función a aplicar y cualquier parámetro adicional que requiera (excepto la columna en sí).

Dicho esto, te diría que tu problema es otro, y tiene que ver con la forma en que `read_sheet()` está tratando las cadenas, evidentemente hay un problema en la lectura de los caracteres unicode. Hay un [`issue`](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/issues/26) al respecto cerrado apenas hace 26 días, dónde la solución que plantean es actualizar el paquete `gargle` que usa internamente `googlesheets4`. Puede probar actualizar el mismo mediante `install.packages("gargle")` o bien instlar la última versión de desarrollo: `devtools::install_github("r-lib/gargle")`

Comment: Excelente Patricio, muchas gracias!